# How to get multiple plots per variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm not sure how to make multiple plots per variable. So I would like to have something like this: [image]

My data looks like this

```
> head(Captiv_mean)
  Participant.Code Condition     Class.1 Upper_Left_Arm_RULA Upper_Right_Arm_RULA Neck_RULA Trunk_RULA
1           AE1_01       DBG Calibration            1.187500            1.2155172 3.3225575  0.4798851
2           AE1_01       DBG     Sitting            2.962401            3.0016527 5.1971110  2.8696135
3           AE1_01       DBG    Stepping            2.494737            1.9894737 4.6052632  1.4052632
4           AE1_01       PRE Calibration            1.678552            1.2618384 5.5771588  0.6072423
5           AE1_01       PRE       Other            0.132678            0.1103238 0.6377426  0.2530313
6           AE1_01       PRE     Sitting            2.013686            1.6693523 5.8169352  1.7554690
```

I would like to have a 1 graph PER "Class.1" (there are 4 different ones in total, so that all the data per "Class.1" is grouped within their on graphs (you can ignore the first column). It is important to note that I need the data within each graph to be grouped by the column "Condition". Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Instead of providing `head(Captiv_mean)`, can you edit your question to provide `dput(Captiv_mean)` or `dput(head(Captiv_mean))`?

Comment: I agree in general to a preference for `dput` for sample data, especially when there are (1) embedded spaces _anywhere_; or (2) non-obvious classes such as `POSIXt` or `Date`, or strings looking like numbers; or (3) presence of list-columns or non-standard column names. In this case, we can get away without it by copying the seven lines (I edited to be full-row lines) and then running `read.table(text = <paste>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ggplot2 especially, it's often good to "melt" (reshape from "wide" to "long") the data. I'll use `tidyr::pivot_longer` for this, though it's easily done using `reshape2::melt` (and `data.table::melt`).

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
pivot_longer(Captiv_mean, -c("Participant.Code", "Condition", "Class.1")) |>
  ggplot(aes(Class.1, value, fill = Condition)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))
```

[image: grouped ggplot boxplot]

The `position_dodge(..)` is needed because the sample data does not include values for all combinations of `Class.1` and `Condition`, causing some groups to have different widths. Without `position=..`, we see:

[image: grouped ggplot boxplot with missing levels]

---

Data

```r
Captiv_mean <- structure(list(Participant.Code = c("AE1_01", "AE1_01", "AE1_01", "AE1_01", "AE1_01", "AE1_01"), Condition = c("DBG", "DBG", "DBG", "PRE", "PRE", "PRE"), Class.1 = c("Calibration", "Sitting", "Stepping", "Calibration", "Other", "Sitting"), Upper_Left_Arm_RULA = c(1.1875, 2.962401, 2.494737, 1.678552, 0.132678, 2.013686), Upper_Right_Arm_RULA = c(1.2155172, 3.0016527, 1.9894737, 1.2618384, 0.1103238, 1.6693523), Neck_RULA = c(3.3225575, 5.197111, 4.6052632, 5.5771588, 0.6377426, 5.8169352), Trunk_RULA = c(0.4798851,  2.8696135, 1.4052632, 0.6072423, 0.2530313, 1.755469)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```